# how to share files with other Mob phone connected to the same network with which you are connected?

Tags: android, tcp, wifi, dhcp

I want to share file from my Mob Phone to other Mob Phone which are connected to the same network with which i am connected, is it can do easily with tcp or dhcp or socket, please i don't know about all of these also.

Answer (score 1):

yes u can share the file through socket communication. Implement the server socket from the device which has the file. And client socket in the other device.
here is the link which shows simple socket communication http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html
Once socket communication is done , read data from the input stream in a loop as long as data is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can share your file with other mob phone which are connected with same network with which you are already connected.
Now how to share these files between parties, see this articles it will solve your problem

[Sending file from one client to another client using socket in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097455/sending-file-from-one-client-to-another-client-using-socket-in-java?rq=1)