# How to share screen of one android device with other through WIFI?

Tags: android, wifi, screensharing

In my Android application one Mob Phone will share the desktop screen with other Mob Phone both connected to the same network. So how it is possible to view all the files of One Mob phone from other Mob Phone through WIFI? is there any socket programming idea used, please elaborate  the solution

Comment: Why you are asking same question again ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994865/how-to-share-files-with-other-mob-phone-connected-to-the-same-network-with-which

Comment: Learn Client Server programming. Launch your server on one Mob and launch your client on other Mob, and then do whatever you want to do.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh So, if want to get services from client as like server then will it b possible, for example as like a bluetoth where when device connected then they can share file from both side, so can i do this with socket programming

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say but yes you can share anything using Client Server architecture and when I say anything then it includes file names, files, songs, images etc. In short anything that one Mob has can send to other Mob with this architecture.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh that great, and the one thing which still stuck in my brain, will it be possible to communicate on both sides, as i have seen in  many articles that one will be server and other will be client, and client will be send data to the server through its designated port no, so i think it will be in bidirectional.

Comment: Communication will be bi-directional, who can start communication depends on who is server and who is client. Client can start communication anytime, server just sits and listen. Once communication is happening, its bi-directional.

Comment: Do u want to watch screen of one phone on other's screen or share file over wifi?

Comment: @user1917769 i want both, but at this moment i want to see the screen of one on another, means desktop sharing. so how can i do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use android screenshot library(http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/) for getting phone's screenshot and send them to other phone

Comment: So i have connected two mobile phone through wifi and ASL library perform an action on one side and will send this pic to other side, so this ok...but when i'll click on any file of the image which i have received then how it will open that file in other Phone, actually i want that one device share his desktop with other and the other will control its file upto some extent, is it possible with sending mouse position findin

Comment: what do u mean by clicking on any file of the image?If u want to control other phone then u will need rooting on that phone.

Comment: i don't understand "Rooting on phone". is this method will show me all the file of other device in my device and then i'll be able to control it. please elaborate little bit about that. thanks for previous comments that so helpful.

Comment: rooting gives root access to user(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_rooting).(1)If you want full control of other phone then 1st u need rooting on that phone to give ur application root priveleges that will accept data from ur 1st phone and will change it to needed actions.(2)If u want file transfer between phones then 1st send all file name to other device.Show them in a list manner,when user clicks on any item then start file transfer(rooting not needed)

Comment: thanks for continuous help from a long time. i have some idea about file transferring but have't about rooting, i will study it myself. when i'll get a problem, then will post here for your suggestion.